# Is a primarily prime TM decidable?

Tags: theory, automata, computation-theory, turing-machines, decidable

A language L over alphabet Σ is primarily prime if and only if for every length l, the majority of strings of length l do belong to L if l is a prime number, but do not belong to L if l is a composite number. Let PriPriTM = {〈M〉 : L(M) is primarily prime and M is a TM}.

Is PriPriTM Turing decidable?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated decision problem, but the answer is that no, it cannot possibly be decidable whether a TM accepts a primarily prime language. Why? Some TMs accept primarily prime languages (consider a TM that accepts exactly the strings of prime length) and some do not (consider the TM accepting the complement of the former's language). The property is semantic in that it deals with what strings are in the language - rather than syntactic, dealing with the form of the TM itself. In other words, two TMs accepting the same language would always be treated identically by a decider for our problem. By Rice's theorem, then, the problem of deciding whether a TM decides such a language is not computable.